# Evaluate the Limits that Exist without L'Hopital's Rule

Tags: calculus, limits

I have four limit problems, for homework, but I don't quite understand them. I will only ask for help on one of them because that should be all I need to understand these. According to the Calculus professor, 'I do not know L'Hopital's Rule, yet.' Therefore, I may not use it L'Hopital's Rule. We have went as far as to understand $\lim_{x \to 0}$$\frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$.

The problem is:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2-x}{\sin3x} $$

Thank you, for your help.

-Rux

Comment: What else do you know as far as the class is concerned?  Are you familiar with the sum expansion of $\sin x$?  How many terms would be required to solve this problem?

Comment: take out $x$-factor common from numerator, and use [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1/393776) to show that the limit is $-1/3$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:
$$\frac{x^2-x}{\sin 3x} = \frac{x(x-1)}{\sin 3x} = \frac{3x}{\sin 3x} \cdot \frac{x-1}{3}$$

Comment: Okay, I understand this. Thank you, for the help. I can get it from here.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Just to continue with this answer, you factor our the $\mathcal x$ from the top in the first step. Then, you can multiply the top and bottom by 3 and split that up into the final equation you have listed. I see that $\frac{3x}{\sin 3x}$ is equivalent to $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ which is 1. So the next step would be $\mathcal x $-$\frac {1}{3}$? And, so $\mathcal x = 0$, since the limit is $\lim {x \to 0}$.  $\frac{0-1}{3}$ = $\frac{-1}{3}$?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Divide the numerator and denominator by $x$

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow0} \dfrac{\frac{x^2-x}{x}}{\frac{\sin 3x}{x}}= \lim_{x \rightarrow0} \dfrac{x-1}{\frac{\sin 3x}{x}}$$

Can you use any formula for limits in the denominator now?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \dfrac{\sin x}{x} =\ldots$$